# How can I only select some JSON objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi I have a script which parses a local JSON object (at the moment just to display a list).

```
function generateFamilySelect() {
    var implantData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("implantData"));
    var implantFamilies = "";
    $.each(implantData.implantFamilies, function( index, value ) {
        implantFamilies += implantData.implantFamilies[index].familyDisplay + "<br />";
    });
    $("#holderForFamilySelect").html(implantFamilies);
}
```

and the JSON object:

```
{"implantFamilies":[
    {"id":"1","familySelector":"aa","familyDisplay":"One","loadInitially":"1"},
    {"id":"2","familySelector":"bb","familyDisplay":"Two","loadInitially":"1"},
    {"id":"3","familySelector":"cc","familyDisplay":"Three","loadInitially":"1"},
    {"id":"4","familySelector":"dd","familyDisplay":"Four","loadInitially":"0"},
    {"id":"5","familySelector":"ee","familyDisplay":"Five","loadInitially":"0"},
    {"id":"6","fami…
```

At the moment, the list shows all of the elements. How can I modify this script to only show those with `"loadInitially":"1"`?

---

Also, a quick syntax question, I feel like the line

```
implantFamilies += implantData.implantFamilies[index].familyDisplay + "<br />";
```

could be written something like

```
implantFamilies += this[index].familyDisplay + "<br />";
```

but I can't get that to work...

Comment: You have to just check for that case before adding to the variable `implantFamilies`

Comment: Just as a note: While you are using a JSON string, once you parse it you have a JavaScript object.  There is no such thing as a JSON object ;)

Comment: To clarify what @JeremyJStarcher said. JSON literally means "Javascript Object Notation". Sure, its pedantic. I even hear it often, but similar to saying "ATM Machine". The acronym already states it is an object, much like the acronym for ATM already states it is a machine. See also: "PIN Number" , etc.

Comment: @the_5imian It it were JUST a pedantic issue, I wouldn't care (as much).  The problem is that people assume that a JSON object is somehow special or different from "regular" JavaScript Objects and arrays, hence, they don't ever look for normal answers, or they pass them up because the answer mentions an "object" or an "array" and they are clearly dealing with a "JSON" something.  The misunderstanding causes *real* problems.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher sure. most people don't know that Arrays -are- javascript objects. But yes, it is still pedantic. Also to be fair,  they actually are "special or different" from normal objects. Namely, they are serializable, which means you cannot attach functions, they will get stripped in serialization. This means that prototype or factory objects with a lot of functions (like jQuery) cannot also be JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[the_5imian has provided a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39813964/3773011) to your first question, and [you have determined the obvious alternate solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39813962/3773011), given your current code.

As to your second question (`this` within [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)):
Within [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), `this` is the `value` wrapped as an Object. `value` is the value of the array element at the current index, not the entire array. In other words, you don't use `[index]` on `value` or `this` within this context to get the current array element. For this code, `value` and `this` are the same because `value` is already an Object.

For what you want, you could just use `value` (Given that all elements of the array are already Objects, you could use `this` instead, but using `value` is a better habit to be in.):

```
$.each(implantData.implantFamilies, function( index, value ) {
    if (value.loadInitially == "1") {
        implantFamilies += value.familyDisplay + "<br />";
    } else {
        //do nothing
    }
});
```

**`this` is the `value` wrapped as an Object:**
The following should show you what the values of `value` and `this` are within `$.each(array,function(index,value){...});`:

```js
var myArray = ['zero','one','two','three','four','five'];

$.each(myArray, function(index,value){
  console.log(index + ' value =',value);
  console.log(index + ' this =',this);  //this is the value wrapped as an Object.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest is to use the Javascript `Array.filter()` method

```
// (or in your case, you get it from localstorage, but here's the data)
var myJson = {"implantFamilies":[
    {"id":"1","familySelector":"aa","familyDisplay":"One","loadInitially":"1"},
    {"id":"2","familySelector":"bb","familyDisplay":"Two","loadInitially":"1"},
    {"id":"3","familySelector":"cc","familyDisplay":"Three","loadInitially":"1"},
    {"id":"4","familySelector":"dd","familyDisplay":"Four","loadInitially":"0"},
    {"id":"5","familySelector":"ee","familyDisplay":"Five","loadInitially":"0"}] };

//the array of implant families  
 var implantFamilies = myJson.implantFamilies; 

//the filtering function. This is preferable to $.each
 function implantFamiliesThatLoadInitially(implantFamily){
    return implantFamily.loadInitially === '1';
 }

 //this is only the ones you want, (filtered by loadInitially property)
 var loadInitiallyImplantFamilies = implantFamilies.filter(implantFamiliesThatLoadInitially);
```

The goal of the second part of your code is to build some html based on the data in the json, stored in teh variable `implantFamilies`. I will recommend Array.map() as an easier solution, than dealing with `this`. like before I am breaking this into multiple steps with comments so it is clear what is happening.

```
//your map function. You can make any html you want, like li's
function toImplantFamilyHtml(family){
    return family.familyDisplay + '<br />'
}

//returns a plain string of html
var implantFamilyHtml = loadInitiallyImplantFamilies.map(toImplantFamilyHtml);

//jquery object you can use, or append to the DOM or whatever
var $implantFamilyHtml = $(implantFamilyHtml);

//append to DOM
$("#holderForFamilySelect").html($implantFamilyHtml);
```

working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mv850pxo/2/

Comment: thanks for this answer. I marked the other one as the solution because it answered my original question, but this info is extremely useful. I didn't know about map() and it looks like it'll come in handy! Thanks!

Comment: I will tell you that 9/10 times in javascript when you think you need `this`, you probably don't. Its handy for delegation, and beyond that its better to prefer pure functions like `filter`, `map`, `reduce`.

Answer (score 0):

Well that just seems obvious now.

```
$.each(implantData.implantFamilies, function( index, value ) {
    if (implantData.implantFamilies[index].loadInitially == "1") {
        implantFamilies += implantData.implantFamilies[index].familyDisplay + "<br />";
    } else {
        //do nothing
    }
});
```

How about the second part of my question?